# Why does Caliburn.Micro.Start use the name "Shell"?

Tags: caliburn.micro

The Caliburn.Micro.Start package provides the files IShell.cs, ShellView.xaml, and ShellViewModel.cs. I understand how these files operate and how they are wired into the provided AppBootstrapper. What I'm not so clear on is the name "Shell," in particular why is it called that. Is the word meant to connote:

1. These files are a template/sample/skeleton window; a "shell" of a window.
2. These files are intended to contain the "launching" point of the app. The command line (if any) could be parsed here and then the appropriate "main" window could be displayed from here.
3. These files are meant to be used as the "main" window of the app, or the app's "shell." I've actually renamed these files to IMainWindow, MainWindowView, and MainWindowViewModel and run with that.

I'm feeling pretty dense asking this question. I know that IShell is a view model and ShellView is the view for that view model, the name just seems curious to me and maybe I'm reading too much into the name?

Comment: It has no significance, but it just seems to be a trend of naming an area of the application which is a shell that contains all the content shown within the application. Atleast from my view-point.